# Check if a .xaml file is valid or not

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception, resourcedictionary

I am making a translation system with resource dictionaries in WPF.
But I have a problem, when I try to load an invalid xaml file in a resource dictionary (like this):

```
// Path is the path of my .xaml file (the file is invalid for the tests)
try {
    Current = new ResourceDictionary() {
        Source = new Uri(path)
    };
} catch (Exception e) {
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

It's throwing an exception. If it's just that I can just catch it, and I know if the xaml file is valid or not.

But the problem is: The try catch do not get the exception. The exception still make my application crash and I do not know why.

I really want to be able to just know if a file is valid or not. (To prevent the app to crash if the user just set the path to a not valid xaml file)

So does someone know how to catch the exception, or to just know before loading the xaml file if it is valid?

EDIT: The exception is: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: `The exception still make my application crash and I do not know why.` How **specifically** does it crash?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the exception is: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
// Check if file content is valid
try { 
    XElement.Load(path); 
    // The file is valid
} 
catch { 
    // The file is not valid
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: That will just ensure it's valid as xml. Rather more to xaml than that.

Comment: Yes but that's ok for me ^^